# Is it ok for an HTML element to have the same [name] as its [id]?

Tags: html, flash, embedding, object-tag

I'm working on embedding a flash app in a webpage using the Satay method:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="embeddy.swf"
id="embeddy" name="embeddy">
  <param name="movie" value="embeddy.swf" />
</object>
```

I want flash to provide the correct `objectID` in `ExternalInterface.objectID`, which means I need to set both the `name` and `id` attributes for the `object`.

Normally I try to avoid naming collisions with elements in HTML, but is there anything wrong with setting both attributes to the same value in this case?

What about HTML forms? Does anyone feel that it's worthwhile to set a(n) ( `input` | `select` | `textarea` ) element's `name` and `id` attributes to the same value?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You use IDs for JavaScript manipulation.

You use Names for form field submission.

The two are not related. So setting both to the same value is OK, but it is not required.

Comment: Also, IDs should be unique, but names do not have to be unique.

Comment: Ida are also used for linking by fragment identifier, and for styling via their use in CSS selectors

Comment: Ids are for easier JavaScript manipulation, but it is possible do do some things by name using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for an answer to this for a while

Answer (score 11):

Not only is it okay, it's quite common.

IDs are used for Javascript (and to a lesser extent, for CSS).

Names are used for form fields to specify the name for the submitted value.

However older versions of IE have known bugs that mean you're almost forced to specify them both the same in many cases. (assuming you want to support those older versions of IE, of course!)

The one thing to bear in mind though is that that IDs must be unique. Therefore, if you have radio buttons which all have the same name, you can't use the same ID for them all. In most other cases though, it's perfectly fine to have them the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yup!  This is absolutely fine.

*id* is the client-side identifier (for when looking up an element in the DOM)

*name* is used during form submission to POST/GET the values.

Outside of an input element there should be no need to use *name* at all.  But giving input elements an *id* allows them to be looked up in the DOM in a consistent fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered the [HTML4 answer to my question](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3):

> The id and name attributes share the same name space. This means that they cannot both define an anchor with the same name in the same document. It is permissible to use both attributes to specify an element's unique identifier for the following elements: `A, APPLET, FORM, FRAME, IFRAME, IMG, and MAP`. **When both attributes are used on a single element, their values must be identical.**

Now, I assume that the rule being applied to `applet` and `iframe` should, by extension, work for `object` and `embed` tags. In any event, using an identical name & id has produced no unusual events to date.

Answer (score 1):

I do it all the time (mostly because some browsers in the past - IE comes to mind - only use the name parameter when sending the form data).  Using id's makes form validation code much cleaner, IMO.

Comment: Browsers are only *supposed* to use the name parameter for sending form data

Comment: Although you wouldn’t use the same `name` and `id` value for radio buttons, or checkboxes that are members of a group, because groups of radio buttons/checkboxes are sort of identified by them all having the same name.